# Display all image files from a directory into WordPress template page

Tags: image, wordpress, templates, themes, glob

I've been refraining from posting in here as I feel it's such a simple question that's been answered many times over and over again. I know this because I've read through countless posts people have made asking the same thing, but for some reason I am unable to get the same results.

What I need is fairly simple. I need to display all of the images from a directory relevant to the current page and parent page in a template file for a WordPress page.

First of all, let me point out that I am able to get this code working outside of WordPress so I am lead to believe that there is an issue with the way content is being delivered within the template file.

This is the code that I have:

```
<?php
$page_parent = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$current_page = get_the_title($post);
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();                  

$dir = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/assets/'.$page_parent.'/'.$current_page.'/';

$files = glob($dir.'{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $image){
    echo '<img src="'.$dir.$image.'" alt="'.$image.'" />';
};

var_dump($files); // This displays array(0) { }
var_dump($image); // This display NULL              
echo $dir; // This works to display the correct URL.
?>
```

The above code is not displaying any of the images and even if I strip out the `<img>` tags and try a simple `echo $image;` it still won't even show me the filenames. However, `echo $dir;` works and displays the correct url which is a direct path to `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/assets/Photography/Holga/`

When I do `var_dump($files)` all I get is `array(0) { }` and when I do `var_dump($image)` all I get is `NULL` yet outside of WordPress it will display the data.

I'm aware that the page names may have capitalised titles so I have kept the folder structure consistent, but as I mentioned I am able to make this work outside of WordPress which is killing me!

Does anyone have any suggestions or reasons why this may not work inside of a WordPress page template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the array that is returned from [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir), you want to use `$upload_dir['basedir']` and not `$upload_dir['baseurl']`. This will return the path to the uploads folder rather than the URL for it.

You aren't getting any results because you aren't passing valid paths to [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).
From the **Notes** in the documentation:

> Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't solve everything but it was one of the hurdles that was stopping me from getting what I thought should work. I've sorted the issue out since,  which is most likely one of the many methods I had already tried but failed because of the 'baseurl' error.