# Display all image files from a directory into WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes

Taking notes from this posts - [Display all image files from a directory into WordPress template page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388622/display-all-image-files-from-a-directory-into-wordpress-template-page) - is there an updated answer anywhere?

No matter what I do, no images are shown and the array output is null/0.

```
<?php
$page_parent = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$current_page = get_the_title($post);
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();                  

$dir = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/assets/'.$page_parent.'/'.$current_page.'/';

$files = glob($dir.'{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $image){
    echo '<img src="'.$dir.$image.'" alt="'.$image.'" />';
};

var_dump($files); // This displays array(0) { }
var_dump($image); // This display NULL              
echo $dir; // This works to display the correct URL.
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you even have images in your $dir? Code seems to be fine.

Comment: Yep, 100%.

I now have it outputting this - /home/sites/21b/c/c10d4f6ad2/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scanned-mail/flexx-ltd-401/File-manager-UI-design-Figma-Design-System-Neolex.png - using the following code but I need it to output a path/url that can be used to download/view.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `$uri = substr( $full_file_path, 0, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) );`